# wp_query on 2 post types, one having custom field for further filtering

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

This is my first question on here; I have hunted around for an answer but if it is out there already apologies.

I am using wp_query() to fetch both 'posts' and a custom post type called 'reviews'. However the custom post type has a sub type and I need to filter out all but one of these sub types just for reviews in the same query!

This is where I got to:

```
$type = array( 'post', 'review' );
$args=array(
    'post_type' => $type,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 20,
        'paged' => $paged,
        'meta_query' => array( // I need to filter the review post type further by subtype
            array(
                'key' => 'subtype',
                'value' => 'review'
            ),
        ),
    'orderby' => 'post_date', // Order by date
    'order' => 'DESC',
  );
```

Obviously, when I run this the default post type is not listed as it doesnt have the subtype custom field. How can I only apply this filter (meta_query) to the custom post type in this query and not have it apply to the default post type 'post'?

Thanks in advanced,
Kris...

UPDATE:

OK, I have tried this but with no success - any ideas?

```
$args=array(
    'post_type' => $type,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 20,
        'paged' => $paged,
        'meta_query' => array( 
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key' => 'subtype',
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'subtype',
                'value' => 'review',
            ),
        ),
    'orderby' => 'post_date', // Order by date
    'order' => 'DESC',
  );
```

Comment: Use an `AND` or `OR` `relation`, check out the codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: Thanks Adrian, I'll investigate this...

Comment: OK, I seem to be stuck with trying to match the subtype value where it DOES exist and matches 'review' OR subtype value doesnt exist (for default post type). Hmm basically where I started lol.

Comment: Hmm still no joy with this, any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0):

This will check the 'subtype' only if it exists in the post (not tested)

```
$type = array( 'post', 'review' );
$args=array(
    'post_type' => $type,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 20,
        'paged' => $paged,
        'meta_query' => array( 
            'relation' => AND,
            array(
                'key' => 'subtype',
                'compare' => 'EXISTS'
            ), 
            array(
                'key' => 'subtype',
                'value' => 'review'
            ),
        ),
    'orderby' => 'post_date', // Order by date
    'order' => 'DESC',
  );
```

Comment: Thanks Andre, I gave this a whirl but has the same result as the default post type 'post' doesn't use the 'subtype' custom field!